# Обьединение запросов mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно объединить эти запросы?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT manufacturer_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' ");
    $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT image_size FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_size WHERE cat_id = {$query} AND man_id = {$query1}");
```

Что имею.
Нужно получить полу image_size из таблицы product_size ,
 есть столбцы category_id, manufacturer_id и собственно image_size.

Есть таблица product где есть нужные 2 поля для меня product_id и manufacturer_id
Есть таблица product_category где есть 2 нужных поля product_id и category_id

и входной параметр который у меня есть - product_id 
Спасибо за потраченное время!

и можете книгу хорошую посоветовать, или материалы, чтоб подтянуть свои навыки, и не задавать такие вопросы)

Comment: Я смогу в своем ответе сделать рабочий запрос только в том случае, если покажете структуру таблиц.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    pc.category_id as category_id,
    ps.image_size as image_size,
    p.manufacturer_id as manufacturer_id
FROM 
    product p
LEFT JOIN product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_size ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
WHERE p.product_id = ?
```

Если я правильно понял, что именно нужно. Я убрал префиксы таблиц, добавите сами.

Comment: я немного уточнил информацию в вопросе, если есть минутка.,посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Вообще запрос в моем ответе должен подойти. Судя по описанию, это то, что нужно. А читать лучше официальную документацию и профильные блоги. Лично я не могу посоветовать какие-либо книги.

Comment: `WHERE p.product_id = ? AND cat_id = ? AND man_id = ?` or `WHERE p.product_id = :product_id AND cat_id = :cat_id AND man_id = :man_id`

Comment: @E_p К чему Ваш комментарий? Если добавить ваше условие, работать ничего не будет. Известен только product_id, читайте внимательнее вопрос

Comment: в product_size нет product_id

Comment: я добавил условия LEFT JOIN oc_product_size ps ON p.manufacturer_id = ps.man_id AND pc.category_id = ps.cat_id , но нужно еще добавить условия, для категории. так как пока выводятся все, где есть такой производитель

Comment: `and pc.category_id = ?`

Comment: Если нужно выбирать только с определенной категорией, используйте inner join